# Padding changing the size on an image

Tags: html, css

So im trying to create some padding for my profile_pic div.

This is the html:

```
  <body>
  <div id="content" class="content">
    <div id="profile_pic" class="profile_pic">
    </div>
    <div id="overview" class="overview">
        asdasdasdasdasd
    </div>
    <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
    <!-- Sport, Academic, Other -->
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

and this the css

```
.profile_pic {
    height: 30%;
    width: 15%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image: url("./images/profile_pic.jpg");
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

and this is what the page looks [like](https://gyazo.com/eb15f830572c7d61310cc4c70a3622e2)

when i add the lines

```
padding-top: 10%;
padding-bottom: 10%;
```

[this](https://gyazo.com/1a9c38653a739b635d0d0531571337b6) is what happens to the image

could someone please explain why this is happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;`, it includes padding and border in the element's total width and height. ;)

Here would be the final code.

```css
.profile_pic {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30%;
  width: 15%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-image: url("./images/profile_pic.jpg");
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="content">
  <div id="profile_pic" class="profile_pic">
  </div>
  <div id="overview" class="overview">
      asdasdasdasdasd
  </div>
  <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
  <!-- Sport, Academic, Other -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok so I have changed the css, however the image is still the same distance from the top of the screen as it was before. How would I move it down X amount

Comment: Use `margin-top: 100px;` by example

Comment: Perfect thats worked

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad, let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 1):

Set this property to the image: `box-sizing: border-box`

This way the total size of the image will be calculated including the padding as well, instead of adding the padding size as extra.

Comment: Also, take into consideration that 10% of padding will use the parent element size as a reference, not the size of the image